# maintaining Max Heap Sort while inserting new items

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, math, tree

I have homework to build a banking system, while implementing all the tasks in most efficient way possible.

The program can :

```
1.add a new customer
2.delete an existing customer 
3.find a customer 
4.print the customer with the highest balance.
5.print all customers with a negative balance.
6.deposit/withdraw money
```

I decided to go for the Red-Black tree for the first 3 ones( O(log-n) ).
I'm not sure about the 4-th and the 5-th though.

4: I thought about maintaining a max heap, so that fetching the 'richest' customer would only cost O(1) - the root node.
My max heap code works for randoms arrays(lists) I tried. However, in this specific case, I obviously start with an empty array, which has to be later populated. **When I use my `insert` method in the max heap , it results in an unsorted array**. (Since I basically skip the heap building .. ).
The insert method for the max heap :

```
dataArray.add( newCustomer );
heapSize = dataArray.size();
int i = dataArray.size()-1;
while( i > 1 && dataArray.get( getParentIndex(i) ).getAccountBalance() < newCustomer.getAccountBalance() )
{
     swap( dataArray, getParentIndex( i ) , i );
     i = getParentIndex(i);
}
```

5: I thought about having a linked list of those with a negative balance. 
This way the complexity would be linear when printing them. (RBTree would cost logN even it there are NO customers with negative balance at all).
However, if I delete a customer, I would have to search (O(n)) the customer in that list to remove him , and then the delete function would be ( *RBTree delete* lgn + n *List delete* = n*lgn )

Comment: I suppose balances can change over time. Your list for point 5 will have to be maintained accordingly. BTW O(lgn + n) is O(n), not O(n*lgn). Also, if you're able to guarantee that such a list can be consistently maintained, it means that you can also maintain a single object for point 4 (which is just a max value), making it a constant time operation without needing an extra max heap.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, there's also the option of deposit/withdrawing money.  
Regarding the list, maintaining it (after insertion,deletion and deposit,and it's also true for the max heap ) will not be effective relative to just traversing the RBTree. right? So maybe I should just use the RBTree for everything..  Is it possible at all to take an empty list, and with each new insertion keep the heap sorted ?

Comment: Forget the heap. There's no need to have more data structures than the RB tree. Just use that correctly. You can find the highest balance by descending right child pointers from the root until you're at the rightmost node in the tree. That's the largest entry. You can print all negative values by staring an in-order search and stopping when you find the first non-negative balance.

Comment: @Gene first of all , thank you for the suggestion. Secondly, that means that printing the highest balance would take O(lgn) instead of O(1) that could be achieved by using a heap, if I'm not mistaken(?). Is it impossible to implement it with the heap?

Comment: Also, regarding printing all negative balances - in worst case, it would take O(lgn)  just to find that there are no negative balances in case there are none. Perhaps storing the negative balances in some type of LinkedList would help? O(1) in best case(checking that it's empty) , and linear complexity in worst case.

Comment: It's a wash. Insert time is O(log n). Why would you care that looking up the highest balance is O(1)? Think it through. If the tree has a billion entries, you will traverse ~30 child pointers to get the max.  That will take less than half a MICROSECOND on most any kind of modern hardware. It's rare that speeding up something that fast is necessary. OTOH, maintaining parallel data structures when you don't need them is a bad idea: error prone, tougher to test, tougher to maintain. Poorer memory locality can easily wipe out the difference between O(1) and O(log n). Big O is a tool, not a goal.

Comment: Thanks.You said for printing the negatives to use inorder until first non-negative. I can't seem to figure out how to write that in code. for example 400,-80,600,-200,60 (R/B not relevant in this case). if I do `if(root !=  null) {
            inOrderPrint( root.getTrueLeft() );
            if( root.getAccountBalance() < 0 )
                System.out.printf("%.2f, ",root.getAccountBalance());
            inOrderPrint( root.getTrueRight() );
        }`  that would work but would traverse all of the nodes even after it finds a non-negative

Comment: Also, if I build and maintain the RBTree by customers' balance, how would I implement search function by customer id ?

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain two binary search trees (key will be the unique customer ID), one for customers with negative balance and one for positive balance. And a pointer `richest` which would always point to the customer with the highest balance.

In every balance change you should check if the sign of the balance changed. If so, delete the customer from one tree and add it to the other tree.

And check the current balance against the balance of `richest`, and assign the current customer if his balance is higher.

Complexity would be:

```
1. insert to tree: O(log(n))
2. delete from tree: O(log(n))
3. binary search in two trees: O(log(n))
4. print the customer pointed by `richest`: O(1)
5. in-order run on a binary search tree (the negative one): O(n)
6. find costumer: O(log(n)) + possible deletions and insertions: still O(log(n))
```

Comment: Nimrod thank you very much for the suggestion. From what I gather , time-wise it's the same complexity as using a tree and a heap, right? but space-wise, another tree would need O(n) while the heap only O(1). I've seen a similar solution(using 2 trees) from last year's class , and they deducted points for not being efficient enough on space too.. :/  I'll probably go for your solution if there's no way I could figure out to make it work with a heap though...

Comment: Also, regarding printing all negative balances - in worst case, it would take O(lgn) just to find that there are no negative balances in case there are none. Perhaps storing the negative balances in some type of LinkedList would help? O(1) in best case(checking that it's empty) , and linear complexity in worst case.

Comment: @BVtp the total space used will always be the number of customers, we hold one tree-node for every customer. the two trees make it easier to seperate negative and positive balance. if there are no negative balances then that tree would have only a root and it will take O(1) to check and print `no negative balances`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on top of @Nimrod Morag's solution, to have better `average` and `amortized` time complexities, you can use `Fibonacci-heap` data structure  (ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap and http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/teaching/fibonacci-heap.pdf) and keep a single `fib-max-heap` for the customers (which has a `max` pointer) and you can do all the operations:

```
1. insert (lazily) a customer to the heap: O(1) 
2. delete any customer (or the customer with maximum balance) 
   from heap: O(log(n)) amortized
3. search a customer in heap: O(log(n))
4. print the customer pointed by `max` pointer: O(1)
5. in-order run on the heap and print only the -ve balances: O(n)
6. deposit/withdraw money: O(1) amortized
```